# Can Windows have two or more real (not virtual) LAN connection from one Ethernet?

Tags: windows, ethernet, lan

I am making a C# application and checking MAC address. In my computer there are three wireless LAN connections, two of them virtual and one real connection  as shown in `ipconfig /all`. It also shows one real Ethernet connection. I am wondering if there can be two or more real Ethernet connections from one card. I know virtual can be possible as seen in the image for wireless LAN.

This is the image:

[image]

Comment: are you asking if a network interface can have more than 1 IP address?

Comment: no , if it can have two or more real connection. I have seen virtual connections in wireless LAN

Comment: @Keltari added a image

Comment: define 'real connection'

Comment: @JourneymanGeek not virtual as in the image.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you mean... Are you meaning "Can you connect to multiple wireless networks from the same network adapter"?

Comment: @ElectroPulse no

Comment: Ok... Are you meaning "can a computer have multiple physical network adapters"? If this is still not the case, please try re-wording the question... What you are trying to find out is not very clear.

Comment: @ElectroPulse i have reworded the question.

Comment: You only have one connector on most wired LAN cards, how do you expect to have more than one "real" connection? Even with clarification your question is quite unclear

Comment: If, for example, you have one PCI card with multiple ethernet ports on it (which is entirely possible and not uncommon on workstations/servers), Windows should assign each port its own "connection". Unless configured otherwise through software, each port would have a different MAC address and therefore I guess you could say multiple "real" connections. In ipconfig / certain portions of  the registry this would probably look similar to a machine that had multiple PCI ethernet cards. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there can be more than one real connections if the computer (most likely a server) has multiple ethernet ports.

Comment: i have reworded the question.please check

Comment: For one ethernet adapter, you get only one real connection. But this connection can be assigned multiple IP addresses.

Comment: So every (not real) connection will have virtual in description??

Comment: The word "virtual" will be localized so it IS different, depends on the language settings of Windows.